# Browser service worker - Unchecked runtime.lastError: listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true but the message channel closed

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I am creating a push notification system for browsers.

What works...

If the corresponding website is loaded in the browser and if the browser is in the BACKGROUND the service worker correctly receives the information and pops up the message in the system tray. On clicking a button in that message, it brings the browser window back to focus and performs the action I want.

What doesn't work...

If the browser is closed OR the browser is open but the website is not loaded in any of the tabs, the service worker correctly receives the information and pops up the message in the system tray. However on clicking a button in that message, nothing happens :(

I tried to debug by closing the browser, sending the message, on receipt of message in system tray I manually loaded up the browser to the website and view console debug. When I then click the button in system try message nothing happened but I received the following message in the browser:

> service worker message Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

Could anyone give me any pointers. I've enclosed below the portion of service worker code that is called when a button on the system tray message is clicked...

```
//If a browser window is in background, and the domain of this project is loaded in to it, 
//we force that window back in to the foreground (and re-display the message in the browser again via the postMessage function)
//However this isn't working if browser is closed at point of system tray message receipt...

function returnWindowToForeground(event,_action) {
   event.waitUntil(
       clients.matchAll(
           { type: 'window', includeUncontrolled: true }
       )
       .then(
           (clientList) => {

            var windowWithDomain = clientList.some((windowClient) => {
                var found = -1;
                let url = windowClient.url;
                if( websiteurl == url.slice(0, websiteurl.length) ) {
                    found = i;
                    windowClient.focus(); //Go back to website in browser
                    windowClient.postMessage([currpayload,_action]); //Post message to browser window
                }
                return found;
            });

            //If not found, spawn a new browser tab, load url and post message
            if (windowWithDomain== -1 && clients.openWindow) 
            {
                clients.openWindow(websiteurl)
                .then((windowClient) => (windowClient) ? windowClient.postMessage([currpayload,_action]) : null;

            }
       )
   );
}
```

Thanks for your help, sorry it's a bit long.